# How to get values of one field in array in MongoDB Driver for C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the classes:

```cs
public class Whole
{
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  public string NeededField { get; set; }
  public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
  public string SomeUnnecesaryField { get; set; } 
}

public class Detail
{
  public string NeededField { get; set; }
  public string NotNeededField { get; set; }
}

[BsonNoId]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MyNeededInformations
{
  public string NeededField { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("Details.NeededField")]
  public List<string> DetailsNeededFields { get; set; }
}
```

And I trying to obtain it with projection:

```cs
var filter = someFilter;
var projection = Builders<Whole>.Projection
  .Include(w => w.NeededField)
  .Include(w => w.Details)
  .Exclude("_id");
return Collection
  .Find(filter)
  .Project(projection)
  .As<MyNeededInformations>()
  .ToList();
```

And I receive `DetailsNeededFields` as empty list every time. I want to have list of strings like with standard aggeregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: someFilter},
  {$project: {"_id": 0, "NeededField": 1, "DetailsNeededFields": "$Details.NeededField"}}
])
```

Comment: Shouldn't the element that you're trying to call "Details.NeededField" not simply be "Details" and be a `List<Detail>` rather than a `List<string>`?

Comment: @Llama It is small reproduceable example, in real project Details have many fields, where I need only one of them

Comment: But you're asking for the equivalent of an console aggregate command that I'm pretty sure is invalid. You should at least make that part of your question valid.

Comment: @Llama Projection stage in example is working now - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be achieved easily with the `AsQueryable` interface like so:

```cs
var results = await collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(_ => true)
    .Select(w => new MyNeededInformations
    {
        NeededField = w.NeededField,
        DetailsNeededFields = (List<string>)w.Details.Select(d => d.NeededField)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Will the `(List<string>)w.Details.Select(d => d.NeededField)` be translated to project only one field, or all details will be downloaded? Is it better than `w.Details.Select(d => d.NeededField).ToList()`?

Comment: @LeszekMazur yes only the needed field values will be downloaded. and you can't call `ToList()` as it's not translatable by the driver.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an `IAggregateFluent<T>` from an aggregation? `AsQueryable()` can't be used in this case.